# In a Spring Boot application, how would I catch internally thrown exceptions that would otherwise escape to the client, but not Spring MVC exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a class in my Spring Boot application that handles many specific exceptions automatically, using @ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
```

For instance I catch this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(OptimisticLockingFailureException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> optimisticLockingFailureException(final OptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
    LOGGER.info("Encountered OptimisticLockingFailureException", e);
    ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO("CONFLICT_ERROR", "Object was locked by ano user, please refresh and try again.");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

And even low level database exceptions:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> dataIntegrityViolationException(final DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
```

But sometimes still some exceptions escape to the client that I didn't handle specifically and didn't know about. I cannot predict the names of all exceptions in an increasingly complex application.

So I naively added this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
protected ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> exception(final Exception e) {
    ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO(
            "Test", "test");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

But this catches everything, even Spring MVC exceptions. So now if I do a request to some non-existing endpoint and normally Spring MVC handles this nicely, it now also is caught in my method and I don't want that.

How would I make it so all exceptions emitted after the entry point in my controllers are caught here so that the client never sees a stacktrace, but everything that Spring MVC handles before my code is even entered is handled normally?

Comment: Well, you have to compare your business exceptions coming from your code vs. runtime exceptions thrown by other frameworks. In the first case you can handle all of these exceptions with your mentioned ExceptionHandler nicely. But if you want to catch all 3rd party "framework" related exceptions there is no other way than either exclusively declaring them or listen to all at once.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic that is unfortunate. I would expect there are other people with the simple use case of not wanting to let exceptions escape to the client, without crippling their Spring MVC component. Do you know any other ways? Indeed my own exceptions are easy enough to catch and I already do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler on your ControllerAdvice and overriding handleExceptionInternal if you need to have a common error message. I believe there are some things you would have to add to your application properties.